# Vertically Center TextArea Text

Tags: html, css

I was wondering about the textarea box bit.ly has on the 1st page you log in where they state to "Shorten your links and share from here".

I was wondering how you would go about centering text in a textarea? I don't think there's a command, so how would you hardcode move it down a few spaces. You can't use html tags in the textarea so it's been difficult with

or other  methods

Comment: Could you take a screenshot of the area you are referencing on bit.ly's page? I'm not quite sure I understand.

Comment: As Peter says, if it's the log in section, can you provide a screenshot? Is it the same as the normal front page textbox?

Comment: i'm not sure how to posts screenshots, but it's in this image:

http://c3.yousaytoo.com/rss_temp_image/pics/48/34/75/5566548/remote_image20110501-23665-140xorc-0.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure it's a textarea and not just an `<input type="text">`? If it's the latter, you can achieve the effect quite easily with padding:

```
input[type=text] { font-size: 20px; padding: 5px; }
```

*Edit:* If it's a text area (say with one row), styling via padding works the same:

```
textarea { font-size: 20px; padding: 5px; }
```

Comment: inspect element from google chrome gives:

<textarea id="bentoBoxMainShareBoxTextArea" tabindex="1" name="u" class="shareMessage"></textarea>

Comment: OK, in that case style the `textarea` with padding.

Comment: hmmm i tried that, but that made the textarea bigger, i guess i could try adjusting the height to match it

Comment: Yes, either you leave the height on automatic and the input box grows, or your height is fixed and you will need to adjust the font size and paddings to follow suit.

Comment: Alright, a padding of 60px and a width of 490px is = to a width of 600 px at 5px padding

Comment: Ty for your help, just some weird scaling, but it worked out =)

Answer (score 0):

Set textarea padding and margin 0 and set the line-height.  Or it would be better to use padding like Kerrek posted

You can't center multi line text in a textarea but you can add padding.

```
<!doctype html>
<style>
input[type=text]{margin:0;padding:0;line-height:40px;font-size:40px;}
</style>
<input type=text>
```

Comment: Yeah, centering really only makes sense for 1-row textareas, which is why I would prefer `<input type="text"/>` in your own design.